# Eigenfunctions particular Heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm considering the following discrete heat equation on [N]:

Let $\alpha, \beta >0$, and $u_t(x) : [N] \to [0,1]$ such that

$\frac{d}{dt}u_t(x)=\Delta u_t(x)~$ for $~x \in {2,...,N-1}$.

$\frac{d}{dt}u_t(1)= u_t(2)-2\alpha u_t(1)$,

$\frac{d}{dt}u_t(N)= u_t(N-1)-2\beta u_t(N)$,

$u_0(x)=1$ for all $x \in [N]$.

Here $\Delta$ is the discrete Laplace Operator ($\Delta f(x)=f(x+1)-2f(x)+f(x-1)$).

Now if we consider the r.h.s of the PDE as an operator $L$ on $u_t(x)$, I'd like to know if the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of this operator are known? Since my knowledge about PDEs is quite limited, I would really appreciate any hint or advice.

In the case $\alpha=1, \beta=1$, we can see it as a discrete heat equation on $\{0,...,N+1\}$, with Dirichlet boundaries $u_t(0)=u_t(N+1)=0 ~ \forall t \ge 0$, where the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions are known.

Thank you for your help.

PS: For information, the main interest relies in the biggest eigenvalue.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please be more specific.

Comment: This may be helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_the_second_derivative